# Add one item each time into a cell of dataframe pandas

Tags: pandas

I need to add/append the results of various functions into a dataframe, each result in one cell. In the example below I'm putting only 3 functions. I could add to lists first and then drop the lists into each column, but there are too many functions to do this individually. Any help is most welcome!

```
import pandas as pd

J = pd.DataFrame()
J['f1'] = []
J['f2'] = []
J['f3'] = []
for i in range(1000):
    f1x = i + 1
    f2x = i ** 2
    f3x = 3 * i
    J['f1'].append(f1x)
    J['f2'].append(f2x)
    J['f3'].append(f3x)

print(J)
J.to_csv(r'00/G/graficos/Resultado.csv')
```

Comment: So, to clarify, you're looking to generate a DataFrame using `n` functions each which generate a single value. You're looking for the correct way to do this?

Comment: Solved... (Remended). :) I created empt rows and replace values.

Comment: Hi, Henry Ecker! Yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list comprehension to create the DataFrame directly is likely the most performant:

```
# Create DataFrame from computations
J = pd.DataFrame([[i + 1, i ** 2, 3 * i] for i in range(1_000)])
# Rename Columns
J.columns = 'f' + (J.columns + 1).astype(str)
```

---

This can also be used with `def` functions:

```
def f1(i):
    return i + 1


def f2(i):
    return i ** 2


def f3(i):
    return 3 * i


# Create DataFrame from functions
J = pd.DataFrame([[f1(i), f2(i), f3(i)]
                  for i in range(1_000)])
# Rename Columns
J.columns = 'f' + (J.columns + 1).astype(str)
```

`df`:

```
       f1      f2    f3
0       1       0     0
1       2       1     3
2       3       4     6
3       4       9     9
4       5      16    12
..    ...     ...   ...
995   996  990025  2985
996   997  992016  2988
997   998  994009  2991
998   999  996004  2994
999  1000  998001  2997

[1000 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you! But I receive this msg: 

numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U23'), dtype('<U23')) -> dtype('<U23')

If no have limit for size of code, maybe I can put the complete code. My code is a mess, but I think I can identify these snippets.

Comment: The only thing missing from these code snippets is the `import pandas as pd`. Are you saying you received that error from my code or somewhere in your code?

Comment: I ran your code separately and it's ok. One of the problems with my code was that in some cells the values are strings. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Hick Nax can you also test [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68516153/16343464) and provide us with an example of the functions that should work with text?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best is to take advantage of vector operations:

```
def f1(i):
    return i + 1


def f2(i):
    return i ** 2


def f3(i):
    return 3 * i

xs = np.arange(1000)

pd.DataFrame({f.__name__: f(xs) for f in (f1,f2,f3)})
```

output:

```
       f1      f2    f3
0       1       0     0
1       2       1     3
2       3       4     6
3       4       9     9
4       5      16    12
..    ...     ...   ...
995   996  990025  2985
996   997  992016  2988
997   998  994009  2991
998   999  996004  2994
999  1000  998001  2997
```

Here is a comparison of the [vector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68516153/16343464) and [loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68515663/16343464) approaches:

[image: loop vs vector]

NB. the scales are log! This means the loop gets even worse when n is higher.